# how to Validate user entries, before adding the user in ASP.NET - CreateUserWizard

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I think the question says it all,
using the default template in Register.aspx, I already customized the CreateUserWizard with a Captcha control, i also have some Business logic to be checked before adding the user, I have tried the following way but it didn't work,  the user is being added anyway even if e.Cancel is True

```
   Protected Sub CreateUserWizard1_CreatingUser(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginCancelEventArgs) Handles CreateUserWizard1.CreatingUser
    Dim Captcha As RecaptchaControl = CType(CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("recaptcha1"), RecaptchaControl)
    If Not (Captcha.IsValid and ValidateUserEntries) Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
   End Sub
```

Any Suggestions, How would I do this?

Comment: Hmm...are you sure you're setting e.Cancel to true?

Comment: BTW, besides my answer, I would like to pint out that your code looks good. If your validation is bypassed, it only means that it was valid, so I would recommend you to double check your validation rules, because setting `e.Cancel = True` actually does the trick to stop the creation of the new user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Jupaol said in the question comments, `e.Cancel = True` actually does the trick to stop the creation of the new user, however the reason was the 
`Captcha.IsValid` it was always returning true!, after a little search i got it to work by  getting a [new api key](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net contains several built-in validator controls for this purpose:

- [CompareValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.aspx). Used to compare two values, usually two controls, for example a password and a confirm password. It can also be used to ensure a value of a `TextBox` is of certain type (int, date, bool...)
- [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx). Used to write your custom logic. It contains an event to be executed on the server (when valdiating on the server) and you can specify a JavaScript function to validate on the client
- [RangeValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.aspx). Used to validate a value falls between a specific range
- [RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx). Used to validate values against regular expressions
- [RequireFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx). Indicates a control is required

Once you have added the validators to fulfill your requirements, you would gain automatically JavaScript support and also server side support.

In order to validate the page, you would call validation like this:

```
protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatingUser(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{
   // optionally specify the ValidatinGroup used. this.Validate("validation group"); 
   this.Validate();
   if(!this.IsValid)
   {
       e.Cancel = true;
       return;
   }
   // execute your code
   // call here your domain logic to execute changes
   // remember to apply domain rules in your domain before executing the current changes
}
```

These controls are used to validate the **user input**, guaranteeing that the input **is valid**, however you might need to apply domain validation to guarantee that you can safely execute changes using the current user input against the **current state of your domain**, this validation should be performed in your domain objects or domain commands